# Can I add a member to a Trello list?

Tags: trello, trello-organization, trello-lists

I am managing a group of solo dancers and I'm using Trello to keep track with their performances. I've made a board called Performances 2017. and lists called by the names of performers. I want them to be able to see only their list a.k.a their performances. So I need to add them as members to their lists...Is this possible? And if it is, is it sure that they will not be able to see other performers events?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, it's not possible. You cannot add people to a list or a card without them having access to the whole board. Privacy/visibility in Trello is at the board level. You will need separate boards for each person, if you don't want them to have access to other people's lists/cards. You can, however, `move` cards to specific boards. So you could make a board for each person, invite the specific people to their specific board, make all the cards in one place, and move them to people's specific boards. To make it easier, you could make the initial card in a board, and then `copy` it to the person's private board.